# Windows / C++ fread() stops reading in data from another process

Tags: c++, c, windows, pipe, popen

So I've run into a quite frustrating problem... essentially I'm trying to transfer data between two different programs. The producer program sends data into stdout. The consumer program starts up the producer via _popen() and then uses fread() to read from that process... this works initially, but after maybe 15 loop iterations, the consumer starts reading in 0 bytes every time (even though the producer should still be outputting data).

I noticed if I tune the data-rates down a lot, I don't run into this problem... however that's not really an option, as in a real scenario, the data would be uncompressed video being piped in through ffmpeg.

Here is my consumer program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    FILE * in = _popen("Pipe.exe", "r");

    if(in == NULL){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    int stride = 163840;
    char * buffer = (char*)malloc(stride);

    int bytesRead;
    while(true){
        bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, stride, in);
        printf("%i\n", bytesRead);
        Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

And my producer program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int stride = 163840;
    char * buffer = (char*) malloc(stride);

    char value = 0;
    while(true){
        // This just changes the data for every loop iteration
        for(int i = 0; i < stride; i++){
            buffer[i] = value;
        }

        value = value == 255 ? 0 : value + 1;

        fwrite(buffer, 1, stride, stdout);
        Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is probably because you are writing control characters to the console.  Looks like it is failing on XON/XOFF (CtrlQ/CtrlS).  This method will work if you restrict yourself to printing characters (32-126).  Alternatively use named pipes or the MS I/O routines ReadFile and WriteFile.

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365141(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @cup: _popen uses pipes anyway, the console isn't involved.  I think the problem is that he hasn't specified b for binary in the mode option - though he might also need to change the mode for standard output in the child process, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @cup Limiting the data range from 32-126 never breaks the dataflow so I guess you're right on the control characters. I'll definitely try implementing with the named pipe or perhaps the anonymous one you just linked. Thanks^^

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thats what I was thinking, but the data range 32-126 doesn't break.

Comment: @user3739753: yep, because the C stream is opened in ASCII mode and so is doing weird stuff with the control characters.  The underlying transport is a Windows pipe, which doesn't care about them.  Do try `_popen("Pipe.exe", "rb")` and see if it helps.

Comment: _popen("Pipe.exe", "rb") is the correct solution. Awesomeness.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I bet it was Control-Z (26) that caused the problem; that's the end-of-file character, equivalent to closing the stream. :-)